# How to make a list of values out of a webpage?

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression, pipe, download, stdin

[In this webpage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Special_page#:%7E:text=Special%20pages%20are%20pages%20generated,pages%20lack%20corresponding%20talk%20pages.) there is a list of MediaWiki special pages (i.e. pages of the `Special:` namespace) and I wish to make a simple text list of all these names automatically.

I assume that a matching pattern to match all names, as they appear in that webpage, should be `Special:^[A-Z][a-z]*:`.

How would you suggest to make a simple text list with all the names?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `curl https://the-full-link -s| grep -o 'Special:[a-zA-Z0-9]*' | sort -u` ?

Comment: @ValentinBajrami exactly. In big plea, publish an answer with this, with a few notes about what is actually being done.

Comment: For example I have trouble understand man grep about `-o` "Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line". non-empty parts of a matching line?

Comment: At least aesthetically, shouldn't A-Z come before a-z because the starting letter is capital?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to pipe to strip text?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/694082/what-to-pipe-to-strip-text)

Comment: @Lahor See they's answer, or just prepand `...|awk -F: '{print $2}'` . Using `-P` which is `Perl-regex`  is a neater way to achieve this. Hope it helps

Comment: @they I think not, because the question is different, it **does** contain data that would have prevented me from asking the current question :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean the Special Pages webpage on Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Special_page, which isn't quite what you referenced in your question.

It generates valid XML so it can be parsed by XML tools such as `xmlstarlet`. From this you can list the pages easily enough by identifying them with XPath paths and validating that they start with `Special:`:

```
curl https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Special_page |
    xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//ul/li/a[starts-with(text(),"Special:")]' -n
```

Example output

```
Special:SpecialPages
Special:AllMessages (System messages)
Special:Statistics
Special:Version
Special:SiteMatrix (Wikimedia wikis)
Special:AllPages
Special:AllPages/T
...
```

You can constrain the set of page names returned by altering the path slightly. Originally I was using `/div[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/ul/li/a[starts-with(text(),"Special:")]` but that seemed overly complex for your straightforward request to "*make a list of* all *these names*".