# What to pipe to strip text?

Tags: text-processing, pipe

I download data into a file this way (credit to Valentin Bajrami for the code):

```bsh
curl https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Special_page -s | grep -o 'Special:[a-zA-Z0-9]*' | sort -u > special_page_names
```

I use `Special:` just for an accurate match but actually after the data was downloaded I should not have this `Special:` text.

Right after the `sort`, what could I pipe to remove `Special:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for another pipe. Try this:

```
curl https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Special_page -s | grep -oP 'Special:\K[a-zA-Z0-9]*' | sort -u > special_page_names
```